# ToC level 2 styling on new page, and ToC options

Tags: html, wkhtmltopdf

I have two questions:

1. On [this old manual](https://madalgo.au.dk/~jakobt/wkhtmltoxdoc/wkhtmltopdf-0.9.9-doc.html) I found some useful toc-options like `--toc-depth` or `--toc-l1-font-size`. It seems they aren't available in latest wkhtmltopdf version - so how can I set toc-depth and toc-font-size now?
2. I want every of my sub-chapters (toc-level 2) begin on a new page:

   - When I create one huge .html file, then the toc is correct (sub-chapter are shown as level-2), but the sub-chapter don't start on a new page.
   - When I create multiple .html files instead (one for every sub-chapter) then my sub-chapter do begin on new pages, but they are all shown as toc level-1.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### ToC customization

In the current version, you can use a XSLT file to customize quite anything of the style of the generated ToC. Here are relevant quotes from the documentation:

> The table of content is generated via XSLT which means that it can be
>     styled to look however you want it to look. To get an aide of how to do this
>     you can dump the default xslt document by supplying the `--dump-default-toc-xsl`, and the outline it works on by supplying `--dump-outline`.
>
> The XSLT document can be specified using the `--xsl-style-sheet` switch. For
>     example:
>
> ```
> wkhtmltopdf toc --xsl-style-sheet my.xsl http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qstring.html qstring.pdf
> ```
>
> The `--dump-default-toc-xsl` switch can be used to dump the default XSLT style
>     sheet to stdout. This is a good start for writing your own style sheet

That's what I did to hide specific levels from the ToC. I edited the XSLT file adding a CSS class to `<li>` (line 40 in the default XSLT) and `<ul>` (line 55) elements. In that class name [I counted the ancestor nodes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1473701/xsl-count-nodes-from-root) to get the "level" of depth of the items.

```
<li class="level-{count(ancestor::*) - 1}">
<ul class="level-{count(ancestor::*) - 1}">
```

Then I added some CSS rules adding `<style>` inside `<head>`:

```
.level-2, .level-3, .level-4 {
    display: none;
}
```

#### Page breaks for sub-chapters

You can place a `<div style="page-break-after: always"></div>` in yout HTML **before** your sub-chapters to force them on a new page.

Comment: Thank you! No. 2 worked perfect! No.1: I have to try it, but I have no experience with XSLT - I see come CSS in there, so I think I am able to define font-size - but what about toc-depth?

Comment: What exactly was `--toc-depth` for? I knew nothing about XSLT, too; I had to look a couple of guides before using it for ToC styling.

Comment: It was for toc-level displayed in the toc. Default is `3` (chapter + sub-chapter + subsub-chapter), but I want to set it to `2`.

Comment: Then, you are looking for `--outline-depth 2`.

Comment: No. `--outline-depth 2` prints only 2 level in the bookmark of Acrobat Reader, but the TOC page still shows 3 level.

Comment: Ok, sorry. You can remove levels editing the XSLT, anyway.

Comment: I don't see how to do this via XSLT - I had to remove all my <h3> tags from my HTML files instead.

Comment: Hi @
I am a Python developer, and I am beginner at using wkhtmltopdf, and currently I have a html being converted into a pdf. But I want to automatically include a table of contents. The documentation says I should put a file called toc.xsl into the param toc. But I am not familiar with .xsl files, so I am not sure what that file should contain. I looked online for examples, but I think they are a little beyond me. Can you please help guide me? Thanks!